# How to transpose one or more column pairs to the matching record in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

Given data sets like this:

```
Sheet 1

Col1           Col2         Col3
Miss Molly     Extra Data   Extra Data
Mister Rogers  Extra Data   Extra Data
Roy Rogers     Extra Data   Extra Data
```

and

```
Sheet 2

Col1           Col2           Col3
Miss Molly     Value Name 1   Value Data 1
Miss Molly     Value Name 2   Value Data 2
Mister Rogers  Value Name 1   Value Data 1
Roy Rogers     Value Name 1   Value Data 1
Roy Rogers     Value Name 2   Value Data 2
Roy Rogers     Value Name 3   Value Data 3
```

How can I end up with a transposed output like this?

```
Sheet X (you can make me a new sheet if you like, or add to Sheet 1)

Col1           Col2         Col3        Col4           Col5          Col6          Col7          Col8          Col9
Miss Molly     Extra Data   Extra Data  Value Name 1   Value Data 1  Value Name 2  Value Data 2
Mister Rogers  Extra Data   Extra Data  Value Name 1   Value Data 1  
Roy Rogers     Extra Data   Extra Data  Value Name 1   Value Data 1  Value Name 2  Value Data 2  Value Name 3    Value Data 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub MergeData()
    Dim rSrc As Range
    Dim rDst As Range
    Dim rwSrc As Range
    Dim rwDst As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vCopy As Variant
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rDst = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    vSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange
    ReDim vCopy(1 To 1, 1 To 2)
    Application.FindFormat.Clear

    For i = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
        If vSrc(i, 1) <> "" Then
            ' Find vSrc(i, 1) in rDst.Column(1)
            Set cl = rDst.Columns(1).Find( _
                What:=vSrc(i, 1), _
                After:=rDst.Cells(1, 1), _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False)

            ' Copy data to Dest sheet
            If Not cl Is Nothing Then
                Set cl = cl.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1)
                vCopy(1, 1) = vSrc(i, 2)
                vCopy(1, 2) = vSrc(i, 3)
                cl.Resize(1, 2) = vCopy
            Else
                ' Name not found in Dest sheet
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```