# Excel - transpose pairs of columns

Tags: excel, offset, transpose

I'm attempting to transpose - if that's the right application of the term - pairs of columns into repeating rows. In concrete terms, I need to go from this:

```
Thing1     6    0.29    5   0.23    7   0.19    8   0.11
```

to this:

```
Thing1     6    0.29
Thing1     5    0.23
Thing1     7    0.19
Thing1     8    0.11
```

This operation will occur with at least 7 pairs of columns for several hundred "things." The part I can't figure out is how to group/lock the pairs to be treated as one unit.

In some ways, I'm trying to do the opposite of what is normally done. One example is here: [Transpose and group data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853218/transpose-and-group-data-in-excel) but it doesn't quite fit, even if I attempt to look at it backwards.

EDIT: Another example that is similar, but I need to do almost the reverse: [How to transpose one or more column pairs to the matching record in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919597/how-to-transpose-one-or-more-column-pairs-to-the-matching-record-in-excel?rq=1)

My VBA kung fu is weak, but I'm willing to try whatever your collective wisdom suggests.

Ideas are welcome, and in any case, thank you for reading.

Comment: One way is to transpose the row into a column, apply some sort of test in the two adjacent columns `>1`, `<1` for this example and then remove duplicates (spaces).

Comment: Will you accept a [tag:vba] solution?

Comment: Alternatively, use VBA to run through the row and either apply some sort of test `if cells("A",i)>1 then` or every second cells `if i mod 2 = 0 then` or `if i mod 2 = 1 then`

Comment: Daniel Lee - I think I follow. That could work. Robin Mackenzie - I would, though I'm not experienced with VBA.

Comment: The logic you are proposing seems exactly what I'm looking for - but I'm afraid I'm too much of a VBA noob to know how to formulate it or execute it (sorry). But I'm thankful that you grasp the situation and what is needed! (And yes, the B column will always be whole numbers and the C column will always be less than 1.)

Comment: Please let me know if you have any questions about the solution I posted. Best of luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a VBA solution.

To implement this, press `Alt+F11` to open the VBA editor.

Right click to the left side and select "Insert Module"

Paste the code into the right side of this.

[image: Example]

You may want to change the output sheet name as I have shown in the code.

I use `Sheet2` to place the transposed data, but you can use whatever you want.

After you have done this, you may close the editor and select the sheet with your non-transposed data.

Run the macro by pressing `Alt+F8`, clicking on the macro, and pressing `Run`

`Sheet2` should contain the results you are looking for.

```
Sub ForJeremy() 'You can call this whatever you want
Dim EndCol, OutSheet, OutRow, c, x
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
EndCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.columns.Count

'What sheet do I put these values on?
Set OutSheet = Sheets("Sheet2") 'Put the name in the quotes

OutSheet.Cells.Delete xlShiftUp 'This clears the output sheet.
OutRow = 1
For Each c In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"))
    For x = 2 To EndCol Step 2
        OutSheet.Cells(OutRow, 1) = c.Value
        OutSheet.Cells(OutRow, 2) = Cells(c.Row, x)
        OutSheet.Cells(OutRow, 3) = Cells(c.Row, x + 1)
        OutRow = OutRow + 1
    Next x
Next c
OutSheet.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Input:

[image: Input]

Output:

[image: Output]

Edit: If you wanted to add an additional column to the beginning that would also just display to the side, you would change the code like this:

```
For Each c In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"))
    For x = 3 To EndCol Step 2 'Changed 2 to 3
        OutSheet.Cells(OutRow, 1) = c.Value
        OutSheet.Cells(OutRow, 2) = Cells(c.Row, 2) 'Added this line
        OutSheet.Cells(OutRow, 3) = Cells(c.Row, x) 'Changed to Col 3
        OutSheet.Cells(OutRow, 4) = Cells(c.Row, x + 1) 'Changed to Col 4
        OutRow = OutRow + 1
    Next x
Next c
```

To better explain this loop,

It goes through each cell in column `A` from the top to the bottom.

The inner loop scoots over 2 columns at a time.

So we start at column `B`, and next is `D`, and next is `F` .. and so on.

So once we have that value, we grab the value to the right of it as well.

That's what the `Cells(c.Row, x)` and `Cells(c.Row, x + 1)` does.

The `OutSheet.Cells(OutRow, 1) = c.Value` says - just make the first column match the first column.

When we add the second one, `OutSheet.Cells(OutRow, 2) = Cells(c.Row, 2) 'Added this line` we are saying, match the second column too.

Hope I did a decent job explaining.

Comment: This. Is. Wonderful. I think I can even see how you magic'd this up because of the clarity here, though I may have to do more reading on VBA. Thank you for the time you took in making this easy to understand.

Comment: Glad you found it helpful! `Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"))` This line will basically go through each cell in column `A`, so if you end up having something in a different column, you should be able to change that to `B:B` or whatever else you need. If you do this, just keep in mind that the second loop `For x = 2 To EndCol Step 2` needs to have its `2` changed to match. So if you make it `B:B` for example, you would want to change it to a `3`. If you make it `E:E`, a `6` - and so on.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm reading this right, if I need to add another column, say, an ID number, as ColumnA, (followed by the label "ThingX" and the paired columns) then I will need to change "or x = 2 To EndCol Step 2"  TO  "or x = 3 To EndCol Step 2"  ?

Comment: No, it should automatically detect the number of columns. I just meant if you tried scooting everything to the right or something. You should be able to just paste whatever you need into column A and run the macro.

Comment: Rather, I misread lol - yes, if you wanted to add an ID number or something else that wouldn't be handled as a "pair", it would need to be re-written a bit. Specifically you would want to add some code inside of the loop and change the `2` to a `3`

Comment: You can look at my edit - but if you have two columns that need to be placed to the side, you would just want to make sure that you bring over an extra column in the loop and scoot the output over a column.

Comment: I added another edit to kind of go over the code a bit more if you care

Comment: Ah! I see! Again, thank you so much. You're wonderful, at least to this random person on the internet. If you ever have any SPSS, music or home repair questions, I'm you're guy. But VBA is very new to me, and you made this easy. Now I feel stupid for pridefully trying for a whole day to figure this out on my own. Another lesson learned.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the Excel formula solution just in case. If the source data starts at `A1`, then formula in the first destination cell will be `=$A$1` and the 2 formulas to the right will be

```
= OFFSET( A$1, 0, ROW( A1 ) * 2 - 1 )
```

and

```
= OFFSET( A$1, 0, ROW( A1 ) * 2 )
```

copy the 3 formula cells and paste in the range below them

**Update**

VBA version (set r to the source range and replace c3 with the first cell in the destination range)

```
Set r = [a1:i1]
set d = [c3].Resize(r.Count \ 2, 3)
d.Formula = "=index(" & r.Address & ",if(column(a1)=1,1,row(a1)*2-2+column(a1)))"
```

Comment: I like this a lot - I tend to think in VBA, but formulas can typically handle these things quite well also. I just hate having to manually setup formulas and prefer pushing one button.

Comment: @user1274820 Excel Formulas are usually much faster than VBA (maybe because of the [Multithreaded Recalculation in Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687899.aspx)), so I sometimes use them in VBA to make parts of the code faster.

Comment: @slai Ah, I love the flexibility of multiple solutions! Thank you for contributing. Stackoverflow and its users are a bright spot on the internet.