# Need to convert multiple columns to rows

Tags: excel, rows

I have a data set that looks something like this

```
Host, software 1, software 2. software 3......
```

I need it to look like this

```
host,software 1
host,software 2
host,software 3
```

Any tips or suggestions on this would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: (1) Use `Text-To-Column` to convert the line into several columns, (2) select the result and copy it (3) paste it with the `Transpose` option to column `B` and (4) copy the word `host` all the way down in column `A`. Done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910778/excel-transpose-pairs-of-columns/38924815#38924815

Comment: or you can just copy the data > right-click where you want it pasted > Paste Special > Transpose. Then you can copy `Host` and paste it in the column on the left for it to be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with VBA? if so, try this. Just paste it into a module and run it. I'm sure this is not the most efficient way, but it'll get the job done.

I'm also assuming that you only have 3 software columns. If you have more, you need to change the part that says 'for j = 1 to 3' to say 'for j = 1 to X', where X is the number of columns you have.

```
Sub transfer()

'Please make sure to change the name of the sheets to reflect the _
 correct worksheet names.
Dim wkInput As Worksheet: Set wkInput = Worksheets("sheet1")
Dim wkDest As Worksheet: Set wkDest = Worksheets("sheet2")

'Here we find the maximum number of rows that will be transfered.
Dim nl As Integer: nl = wkInput.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'Here we create a few couner variables.
Dim Row As Integer, Col As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer

'*********Procedure begins here************
Row = 1
Col = 1
For j = 1 To 3
    For i = 1 To nl - 1
        wkDest.Cells(Row, Col).Value = wkInput.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
        wkDest.Cells(Row, Col + 1).Value = wkInput.Cells(i + 1, j + 1).Value
        Row = Row + 1
    Next i
Next j

'*******Procedure ends here*************
End Sub
```